# Send an email to all users in a database

Tags: php, sendmail

How does one go about sending emails to every user within a database without being flagged by any spam filters? I am assuming you would have to send the emails throughout the day in bursts over the course of a month or less. Of course, right off the bat, I can get all users email addresses with a simple query 
`select 'email' from 'users'` but implementing the proper way to do such a task is where I seem to be lost... In the past I have used services such as sendgrid, but what guidelines do these companies follow in order to stay clear of all spam filters?

Comment: Simply answered... Yes. You may have a look at http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=examplebmail

Comment: How may message do you expected to send? [1K, 1M, ...] Do you want to send personalized messages? [e.g. different To; to Subject: in every message?  I am trying to guess if you go above threshold of "big problems at next stage (mail server)".

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Sending about half a million each the same message

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can do it. follow the given code.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $addresses[] = $row['email'];
}
$to = implode(", ", $addresses);
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
mail($to, "Your Subject", "A message set by you.", "If header information.");
```

First you have to gather all the email address as comma separated. after then just use a mail function to send mail to all user at the same time.

If you want to send mail separately then use:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $to = $row['email'];   
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    mail($to, "Your Subject", "A message set by you.", "If header information.");
}
```

**Updates:**
As *mysql_** deprecated please use *mysqli_** instead of all functions.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $addresses[] = $row['email'];
}
$to = implode(", ", $addresses);
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
mail($to, "Your Subject", "A message set by you.", "If header information.");
```

And

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $to = $row['email'];   
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    mail($to, "Your Subject", "A message set by you.", "If header information.");
}
```

Please read the manual of [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: I recommend you NOT to use [mysql](http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysql.php) since its depricated. instead use [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/de/book.mysqli.php) or [pdo](http://php.net/manual/de/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Yes i know, the best way is to use mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I appreciate it and it worked great. Apologies for the very late response.

Comment: How will this code react on email that does not exist. Assume someone subscribed with wrong email that does not exist. Will it issue an error and stop sending emails after that or will it ignore and send to all emails ?

Comment: @bakero98, The email will send to each and every mail address either it is valid or not, PHP check the email address structure only, other task will be done by the mail server. From the mail server the mail may not sent to invalid email address.

Comment: @MuradHasan Thank you. Couldn't find explanation for that in `mail()` manual

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your result set, you can loop through and call `mail()` on each 1. Let's hope that your server can handle this.

```
foreach($result as $user) {
    mail($user->email,"My subject",$msg);
}
```

Comment: I would not recopmmend this way... first, it has a bad performance, second, errors in emails cant be handled without adding check code and third you options are very low when you dont know how to set your header informations. Of course there are some more problems you can run into.. but this is a comment not a post ^^

Comment: Actually it's not a good idea at all. PHPMailer is way better to use and easier as well.

Answer (score -1):

I used [PHPMailer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/) to send emails. It's easy. Simply iterate all emails from DB and send using this library.